# How to propagate guava plant from stem cutting?

Tags: houseplants, propagation

I would like to propagate my guava plant which bears very tasty pinkish flesh fruits. I tried to plant stem cuttings that were dipped in TakeRoot Rooting Hormone powder with no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most reliable way would be through a layer or air layering. Both these methods leave the part you intend to cut off attached to the mother plant so it can continue to grow as it is simultaneously making roots for its own benefit. There are lots of pages and videos available describing how to implement these techniques; they are simple and use little equipment. If you can bend a branch to ground level or raise a pot to the branch then layering would be good, otherwise air layering would be the solution.